# About Form1 design in winforms and its details

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ok guys, i have 2 newbie questions:

1. How to design my form1 window in winforms. Not the things inside like buttons, background etc. but the area around it with borders of the window where buttons "Close window", "Maximize", "Minimize" are placed. 
   I'm making a simple calculator program but what if want it to look like a real calc? I mean design of it. Not a calc with a texture in the window, but calc with texture without that window borders. Is it possible? 
   Can you target for me components of winforms or things in it that i should look for.
2. When i launch my suppa-doopa calc in a window, the one of the buttons is already selected like the cursor was placed on it. How can i recude this to make everything clear?

Comment: Please take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As far as border-style, in the designer of the form there is an option for Border Style. Try adjusting that and see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'd take a look at it. But what about the second question? I know it's small, but still bothers me...

Comment: I added an answer below that should help. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to recap the answers to your questions as an answer.

1. The window buttons you are referring to removing to get a borderless form can be achieved through the designer. Set the border style to "None."
2. One way to prevent a default button from being selected is through the Tab Order. There is an answer on this already on StackOverflow at [Buttons Are Automatically Selected (how to turn this off?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884496/buttons-are-automatically-selected-how-to-turn-this-off) .

Regards and best of luck.